# Why does Hibernate only retrieve the value of the ID column?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I don't detail it more cause I'm almost sure it's something about the config and not something related to hibernate version, but you only have to ask if you need something more =)

The thing is: What could be the problem if when I execute an HQL like this:

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("select foo from Foo foo");
    List<Foo> foos = query.getResultList();
```

Hibernate retrieves Foo objects with id but with all the other columns to null when in the database I see they are informed?

Imagine Foo is:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="FOO")
    public class Foo implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @column(name="F_ID")
        private long id;

        @column(name="F_COD")
        private String cod;

        //setters and getters
        ...
    }
```

The thing is, if I later do this with the informed id of one of the foos, it doesn't get the entire object neither!:

```
    Foo f = entityManager.find(Foo.class, foo.getId());
```

Why does it act like an entityManager.getReference() instead of a entityManager.find()?!

**But** if I do:

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("select foo.id, foo.cod from Foo foo");
    List<Foo> foos = query.getResultList();
```

There they are the lost column values! But the result list has Objects and not Foos.

I'm going nuts, I think it has to be something about the config. The lazy fetch or something alike.

Some experienced developer has some idea? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with lazy fetching.

Check this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

Comment: Thank you @Marc-EmmanuelRamage! I don't know what's happening yet but it gave me some ideas. I found and alternative solution with the last query style, but it's not the solution with the config problem so I will continue searching to post the solution if I find it (=

Answer (score 0):

You can map your class as "fetch=FetchType.EAGER", but, I don't recommend such pratice, because your system will become slow.

So, I suggest you use join fetch into your query.

For more information see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins